# 1 of your app is affected by Google Play's target API level requirements - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I've received an email from Google Play telling me that I have to upgrade the target API level (before August 31, 2023).

So if I go to my android folder -> app -> build.gradle, I assume I'll have to change something here?

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but if I keep it like this targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion and make an update to the Google Play Store,  wouldn't this be fine as well?

Comment: Yes @themag it will be fine to keep targetSdkVersion like this.

Comment: Ok thank you, I rather keep it like this instead of manually changing the number. So keeping it like this or changing to 33, either one should work. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello. I received such an e-mail for my application and I changed them manually like you, but I have a question in my mind. How do I transfer these features I changed? Do I need to update my app to a new version?

Comment: @hasangkz either you got to publish new update to playstore before 31'st Aug or request for extension in play console page.

Comment: @ThinkAndCode thank you for your feedback. so what happens if I don't fix my app before August 31st?

Comment: @hasangkz You cannot publish updates after the dead line

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now as per `google play console` guidelines.

Your app must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher.

```
targetSdkVersion 33
```

From android play console ->

From Aug 31, 2023, if your target API level is not within 1 year of the latest Android release, you won't be able to update your app.

Comment: you won't be able to update your app. - What does it mean? After 31st Aug, we never make any release?

Comment: You will not be able to publish a new update to your app.

Comment: Means before 31 august you have to publish an update by making your target api level within 1year of the latest android release. If you do not update you will not be able to release an update after 31st august.

Comment: You are just repeating google's words, I agree with @RohanPatel that this is actually quite ambiguous !  For example, on 1st September we want to update our app specifically TO TARGET API LEVEL 33, can we or can't we?!  I can't believe that would be the case - it would render it (and countless others) zombie apps.  There is a need to understand this statement from Google beyond the literal words, as it doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes you can't, I am just saying what I received in the email.

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal **target api level within 1year of the latest android release.**...in your statement latest android release means `Android 13` or `Android 14`?

Comment: currently the latest release is android 14 which is target api level 34. and you can only keep latest api level - 1.  In my case my app target api level was 32 so I have to update it to 33 so that it will be target api level within 1year of the latest android release.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this in `build.gradle` (App module) file

```
compileSdkversion 33

targetSdkVersion 33
```

With that, you also have to make behaviour changes for android-13

Comment: Give it more explanation

Comment: You need to add SDK support version in android>app>build.gradle  compileSdkversion 33

targetSdkVersion 33 @ChiragThummar

Answer (score 1):

If your current API level is 31, you are OK.

[image]

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en

Comment: Ok, but then why the alert? I have the same case, my app is targetSdkVersion 31 and I have the same warning. Even with the warning that we won't be able to upload updates later... it doesn't make sense, they are not consistent with this text you show.

Fortunately it let me compile with the modification, but it doesn't make sense.  Either the warning is poorly implemented or the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same problem.

I have an application that is live with Flutter. When I want to upgrade the api level to 33, I get an error and I haven't been able to solve it yet. There are two different errors I get.

1 - A problem occured evaluating root project android cannot run project.afterEvaluted(Clouse) when the project is already evaluated
2 - ext.kotlin.version = <latest.version>

When I upgrade the kotlin version to the latest version, I already get the evaluated error. When I lower the Kotlin level, I get an upgrade to the latest version warning.

Comment: Which kotlin level do you use to pass?

Answer (score 0):

If you build android application using flutter, You need to update gradle file below code, you can also update your native android java/kotlin

[gradle snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tupp0.png)

```
    defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Here is the code snap. and upload it to playstore before 31, August 2023